# Правописание суффиксов

Tags: орфография

В словаре Ожегова нашла слово "ячёнок". Именно так, с буквой "ё". По правилам орфо в суффиксах существительных после шипящей пишется под ударением "о" (зайчонок, бельчонок). Может, знаете, почему в этом слове "ё"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно - **ячонок**. См. "Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук."
Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.

А вот Ожегов устарел =(

P.S. я думаю, что этот тот случай, когда можно писать по-разному, как подсказывает чутье. В любом случае бить никто не будет.

Comment: Ну нет! По-разному писать, как подсказывает чутье, - этак мы совсем растеряем грамотность. Зачем тогда словари?

Comment: Тогда сделайте один общий словарь, чтобы не было противоречий. Ведь не сможете. Главное - уметь аргументировать свою т.з. И не надо говорить, что русский язык обладает регулярной структурой....

Comment: Сделайте. Общий. А подначивать большого ума не надо.  
Кстати, с какого боку тут регулярная структура? Орфоэпические правила к формализации грамматики имеют отношение - меньше чем никакое. Да никто никогда и не говорил о регулярности структуры в целом.

Comment: Открыла Ожегова 1994г. Нет такого слова ни через О. ни через Ё.

Comment: В интернет-версии есть

Answer (score 1):

Не верится, что у Ожегова с ошибками. Открыла Ожегова 1994г. Нет такого слова ни через О. ни через Ё. В Сети действительно есть на  [dic.academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru) › Толковый словарь Ожегова, Шведовой. Вот Шведова могла намудрить. (Ожегов умер в 1964). И то хорошо бы проверить по печатному изданию. 
Помня не очень восторженные отзывы о словаре (с добавлениями Шведовой), не покупала этот словарь. А на сайте ещё и странные выходные данные напечатаны: годы 1949-1994. В 1949 - Шведовой возле словаря не было. Она взялась за него после Ожегова.

Comment: Вот здесь:
http://www.gumer.info/bibliotek_Buks/Linguist/ozhegov/28.php

судя по всему, использую оригинальную ожеговскую версию.

Comment: Нет. Там как раз "ячЁнок".

Answer (score 1):

Словарь Ожегова, Шведовой. М.: Азбуковник, 1999.
Слово написано через "ё". Исправил в словаре.

Answer (score 0):

Не согласна с gecube в том, что главное - уметь аргументировать свою т.з. На экзамене в формате ЕГЭ это не поможет.

Comment: Абсолютно с вами согласна. Как раз по поводу этого правила (правописание суффикса -онок/-ёнок) никаких исключений нет. Тут не может быть никаких разночтений: ячОнок. Интересно, как gecube собирается аргументировать написание этого слова чере Ё?

Comment: Аргументировать - это как раз запросто.  
Русский язык исповедует фонетико-морфологический принцип орфографии - и почему в данном случае правильным должно быть написание, не основанное ни на фонетике, ни на морфологии - совепшенно непонятно))).  

Вопрос - кому такая аргументация пригодится?!

Answer (score 0):

behemothus,

русское письмо исповедует разные принципы. В данном случае действует принцип, который можно условно назвать "слоговым" (*жи*, *ши* пиши с буквой **И**, *ча*, *ща* - с **А**, *чо*, *що* - с **О**).

Comment: grumant, вам бы отсидеться прежде чем опять на рожон-то лезть. )))
Я знаю о принципах русского письма. Их четыре. "Слогового" среди них нет.

Comment: grumant???

Comment: Ларf, я ожидал от вас большего :-). Чего-то вроде "Как так? нет слогового принципа??"

Comment: >grumant???  

Угу. Это к вопросу об умных на форуме. Который так Вас обидел.

Comment: НЕ все я понимаю в Ваших рассуждениях.  Что касается принципов орфографии, они меня не очень интересуют. Да и с официальной терминологией я не во всем согласна. Особенно, когда говорят морфологический, а подразумевают морфемный. Так же, как и в способах образования слов.

Comment: >НЕ все я понимаю в Ваших рассуждениях.   
  
Вы мне? Я знаю. Вы об этом на мете написали. Фразу про умных на форуме точно не поняли. 


> когда говорят морфологический, а подразумевают морфемный.  

Не могу согласиться. Именно морфологический.  
http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=3.4&PHPSESSID=%2C